# Can't insert into mysql when updating gps location from android

Tags: php, android, mysql, gps

A simple android application. This application can get coordinate of user location and sending lat and long to mysql. This is my android code :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

 Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){   
             lat = (float) gps.getLatitude();
             lng = (float) gps.getLongitude();
             lat2= Float.toString(lat);
             lng2= Float.toString(lng);



            insert();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success insert - \nLat: " + lat2 + "\nLong: " + lng2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        }
    });
}

public void insert() {
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat2", lat2));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng2", lng2));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.56.1/rute2/insert_android.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }

    try {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code = (json_data.getInt("code"));

        if (code == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
}
```

and this is table marker_awal

[image]

this is my php file

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$uname='root';
$pwd='';
$db="test";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

$lat2=(isset($_REQUEST['lat2']) ? $_REQUEST['lat2'] : '');
$lng2=(isset($_REQUEST['lng2']) ? $_REQUEST['lng2'] : '');


//$lat2=$_REQUEST['lat'];
//$lng2=$_REQUEST['lng'];

var_dump($lat2);



$flag['code']=0;

if($r=mysql_query("insert into markers_awal values('','$lat2','$lng2','') ",$con))
{
    $flag['code']=1;
    echo"hi";
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I got no error in my application but it can`t insert to database.

Comment: Where are you inserting actually? in your device local database or at server side database?

Comment: in my localhost database @user3764504

Comment: ok, then where is that code? I think you forgot to post it here

Comment: nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat2", lat2));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng2", lng2));
here, are you getting latitude and longitude value for sure?

Comment: @user3764504 , I got this toast , and sucessfully showing mylat and myongtitude Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success insert - \nLat: " + lat2 + "\nLong: " + lng2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: okay, then I think problem is in your php side

Comment: @user3764504 Do you know where is the error? :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56203/discussion-between-user3764504-and-hot-programmer).